# merging and sorting data from two different tables without using a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a header table like this

| id | description | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blablabla | In progress |
| 2 | abcabcabc | Open |

and then I have two more tables:

comments:

| header_id | description | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a very long text | 2022-05-02 |
| 1 | another long text | 2022-05-05 |

status

| header_id | old_status | new_status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Open | In progress | 2022-05-04 |

I am building a query that will give me all the comments and the status changes in a timeline for a specific header id (say 1).

My best shot is to use a subquery with union:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT description, 'none' AS old_status, 'none' AS new_status, timestamp FROM comments WHERE header_id=1
    UNION
    SELECT 'none' as description, old_status, new_status, timestamp FROM status WHERE header_id=1
) ORDER BY timestamp
```

but I was wondering if a better approach exists better without using a subquery or without having two datasets that I have to merge later on PHP
Expected result is:

| header_id | description | old_status | new_status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a very long text | none | none | 2022-05-02 |
| 1 | none | Open | In progress | 2022-05-04 |
| 1 | another long text | none | none | 2022-05-05 |

P.s. I am using Mysql 8

Comment: No need for a subqeury. Simply UNION and ORDER BY.

Comment: Do you need to remove duplicates? (I.e. can you use UNION ALL instead?)

Comment: @jarlh no, there are no duplicates so Union is enough. But the ORDER will be cross the two tables and without the subqury I'll order each table separately (see expected results for an example). How can I do that without the subquery?

Comment: You're not actually using a subquery, just a derived table. with SQL being a declarative language there's nothing wrong with this. And if there's no duplicates you *do* want union all.

Comment: Vice versa, UNION spends time on removing duplicates. UNION ALL returns every row.

Answer (score 0):

> without the subquery I'll order each table separately

No - a `UNION` query can only have one `ORDER BY` and it applies to the complete set of results.

To get your expected results you just need to run the query

```
SELECT 
    description, 'none' AS old_status, 'none' AS new_status, timestamp 
FROM 
    comments 
WHERE 
    header_id = 1

UNION

SELECT 
    'none' AS description, old_status, new_status, timestamp 
FROM 
    status 
WHERE 
    header_id = 1 
ORDER BY 
    timestamp
```